# How to force restart a Windows box using VBScript?

Tags: windows, vbscript, reboot

I'm trying to find a way to force Windows to reboot, and I am running into issues.  I've tried

```
Set OpSysSet = GetObject("winmgmts:{authenticationlevel=Pkt," _
     & "(Shutdown)}").ExecQuery("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where "_
     & "Primary=true")
for each OpSys in OpSysSet
    retVal = OpSys.Reboot()
next
```

I've also tried using the `shutdown -f -r` command, and in both cases I sometimes get no response, and if I try again I get an error saying "Action could not complete because the system is shutting down" even though no matter how long I leave it it doesn't shut down, it still allows me to start new programs, and doing a `shutdown -a` gives the same error.  How can a script be used to force Windows to reboot?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
retVal = OpSys.Reboot()
```

With:

```
retVal = OpSys.Win32Shutdown(6)
```

Comment: I assume you mean Win32ShutDown?

Comment: I'm with Matt, this is the way to go.  MSDN details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394058(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 4):

Well, this uses VBScript -- although truthfully it invokes the same command line shutdown that you're trying to do.  I've tested it and it works.

```
Dim oShell 
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'restart, wait 5 seconds, force running apps to close
oShell.Run "%comspec% /c shutdown /r /t 5 /f", , TRUE
```

What OS are you running against?  This test was against XP.  I wonder if the server OS requires a shutdown code...

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the psShutdown command line utility from Sysinternals now Microsoft.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
'*********************************************************

Option Explicit

Dim objShell

Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

objShell.Run "C:\WINDOWS\system32\shutdown.exe -r -t 0"

'*********************************************************
```

This little script restarts the local computer after 0 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Reset= WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

Reset.run "shutdown -r -t 0", 0, True
```

Or..

```
Shell "shutdown -r -f -t 0"   ' for restart

Shell "shutdown -s -f -t 0"  ' for Shutdown

Shell "shutdown -l -f -t 0"   ' for log off

Shell "shutdown -a "  ' for abort
```